# Hourglass won't go away in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008-r2

... after I add a column to a table.  I've just started using 2008 R2 Management Studio, but I have a few years experience with 2005 Management Studio.  Also, I am connecting to a 2005 instance of a database on a remote server.

1. right-click on a column and select "Modify"
2. supply new column name and datatype
3. click "X"
4. click "Yes" to save
5. have to right-click -> "Refresh" on table, and then the new column  shows up, but the hourglass *never* goes away! (see image below)

Why is this happening?

Running Win7 32-bit/Management Studio 2008 R2 32-bit.  There could be other glitches too, I haven't used it enough yet.

[image]

Comment: My co-worker experiences the same issue on his similar setup PC

Comment: Restarting Management Studio makes it go away, but then when I do something else, it comes back again.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug in the software.  Submit it to connect.microsoft.com to have the dev team look at it.

Comment: I did: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlkjmanageability/thread/4ab1fb20-35e2-43d8-bd48-32cdf409586b

Comment: That's an MSDN forum post.  Connect is different. Connect is the bug tracking tool where Microsoft's customers can create bugs for the various product teams.

Comment: +1 good point: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/582590/hourglass-won-t-go-away-in-sql-server-2008-r2-ssms#details